# Stochastic Fubini (Da Prato & Zabcyzk)

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-pde

I've been studying Da Prato & Zabcyzk's text on SPDE, and there's a part of their proof of the stochastic Fubini theorem that I don't quite get.  The setting is that $\Phi: (\Omega_T\times E, \mathcal{P}_T \times \mathcal{B}(E))\to (L_2^0, \mathcal{B}(L_2^0))$, such that 
$$
\int_E \|\Phi(\cdot, \cdot,x)\|_T\mu(dx)< \infty
$$
where $\mu$ is a finite positive measure and the $T$ norm corresponds to
$$
\|\Phi\|_T^2 = \mathbb{E}\int_0^T\|\Phi(s)\|_{L_2^0}^2 ds
$$

The authors have an intermediate result, Prop 4.34 in the 2014 edition, that $\Phi$ can be approximated by a sequence $\Phi_n$ of analogously measurable processes that can be written as simple processes and converge in the sense of 
$$
\int_E \|\Phi(\cdot, \cdot,x)-\Phi_n(\cdot, \cdot,x)\|_T\mu(dx) \to 0.
$$

I find myself unsure of the proof of this intermediate result in that the authors first assert the existence of a sequence $\Psi_n$ (not neccessarily simple) which are bounded and converge in the above sense.  It is clear from the above assumption that $\mu$-a.e., there are processes $\Psi_n(\cdot,\cdot,x)$ which converge in the $T$ norm.  This follows from a Prop 4.22 of the text, and it is clear that they can be taken such that
$$
\|\Psi_n(\cdot,\cdot,x)\|_T \leq 2\|\Phi(\cdot,\cdot,x)\|_T.
$$
How can I infer that this sequence $\{\Psi_n\}$ is then bounded as a mapping over all three arguments $(x,t,\omega)$?