# Properties of Hilbert space valued functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a Hilbert space valued function, with $Y$ a separable Hilbert space and $X$ a measurable space.  Furthermore, assume that
$$
\int \|f(x)\|_Y \mu(dx)<\infty,
$$
for $\mu$ is a positive, finite, measure on $X$ and an associated $\sigma$-algebra.

At each value of $x$, $f(x)$ is to be approximated by simple functions of the form
$$
f_n(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{J_n} c_j^n e_j 1_{A^n_j}(x)
$$
where $e_j$ are an orthonormal basis of $Y$, $A^n_j$ are measurable subsets of $X$ and $c_j^n$ are scalar coefficients.  The goal is for these to satisfy
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int\|f(x) - f_n(x)\|_Y\mu(dx)\to 0
$$

Two questions:

1. Can we say anything about the measurability, in the $x$ argument, of the $\{f_n(x)\}$?
2. Can we say anything about the boundedness (in the $Y$ norm) of $\{f_n(\cdot)\}$ over both $x$ and $n$?

I am attempting to reformulate a more complicated problem (originally asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3022151/stochastic-fubini-da-prato-zabcyzk) into what I believe are its essential elements.

Comment: It is not clear how you're defining $f_n$

Comment: By the separability of $Y$, at each $x$ I can identify a sequence $f_n(x)$ such that $\|f_n(x) - f(x)\|_Y\leq 1/n$, for example.

Comment: That's true regardless of the separability of $Y$.  Do you mean to say that there is a countable subset $Y_0$ of $Y$ such that $f_n(x)\in Y_0$ for all $x$ and all $n$?

Comment: Are you looking for a clearer definition of the construction of the sequence?

Comment: Yes.  You claim to be using separability of $Y$, but according to your definition this is not required.  For instance, just take $f_n(x)=f(x)$ for all $n$.

Comment: See the edits to the original question

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand the definition of $f_n$.  I *think* I know what you mean but I need to be sure. It sounds like you're asking for a sequence of simple functions $f_n$ such that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ almost everywhere.  Is that all you mean?

Comment: Yes, I have simple functions which converge, strongly, point wise in $Y$, and I want to conclude something about the constructed sequence.